# Dynamic SQL: CASE expression in HAVING clause for SSRS dataset query

Tags: sql, dynamic, reporting-services, case, having

One of my tables contains 6 bit flags:

```
tblDocumentFact.useCase1
tblDocumentFact.useCase2
tblDocumentFact.useCase3
tblDocumentFact.useCase4
tblDocumentFact.useCase5
tblDocumentFact.useCase6
```

The bit flags are used to restrict the returned data via a HAVING clause, for example:

```
HAVING tblDocumentFact.useCase4 = 1     /* '1' means 'True' */
```

That works in a static query.  The query is for a dataset for a SQL Server Reporting Services report.  Rather than have 6 reports, one per bit flag, I'd like to have 1 report with an @UserChoice input parameter.  I'm trying to write a dynamic query to structure the HAVING clause in accordance with the @UserChoice parameter.  I'm thinking that @UserChoice could be set to an integer value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6) when the user clicks a 1-of-6 option button.  I've tried to do this via CASE expressions as shown below, but it doesn't work--the query returns no rows.  What's the correct approach here?

```
HAVING  (
        (CASE WHEN @UserChoice =1 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1' END) = '1'
  OR    (CASE WHEN @UserChoice =2 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase2' END) = '1' 
  OR    (CASE WHEN @UserChoice =3 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase3' END) = '1' 
  OR    (CASE WHEN @UserChoice =4 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase4' END) = '1' 
  OR    (CASE WHEN @UserChoice =5 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase5' END) = '1' 
  OR    (CASE WHEN @UserChoice =6 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase6' END) = '1' 
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rephrase your logic slightly:

```
HAVING
    (@UserChoice = 1 AND 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1' = '1') OR
    (@UserChoice = 2 AND 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase2' = '2') OR
    (@UserChoice = 3 AND 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase3' = '3') OR
    (@UserChoice = 4 AND 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase4' = '4') OR
    (@UserChoice = 5 AND 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase5' = '5') OR
    (@UserChoice = 6 AND 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase6' = '6');
```

A `CASE` expression can't be used in the way you were using it, because what follows `THEN` or `ELSE` has to be a literal value, not a logical condition.

Comment: Another good reason not to use ' to surround identifiers, as the original query would have emitted those literal strings? Also if the data type is bit I would advocate replacing `'1' -> 1`

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't know SSRS...maybe it requires them or at least accepts them?  Yes, I agree with you in general.

Comment: Tim/Caius: Thank you both very much.  It works when I combine Tim's rephrased logic with Caius's suggestion, thus: HAVING (@UserChoice = 1 AND dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1 = 1) OR ...  I haven't tried it in SSRS yet; I'm still experimenting in SSMS but I'm happy with this progress.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on the comment under Tim's post, I think the reason it doesn't work out is because your cases are emitting strings containing column names not the values of columns

```
HAVING
  CASE WHEN @UserChoice = 1 THEN dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1 END = 1
  OR CASE WHEN @UserChoice = 2 THEN dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase2 END = 1
 ...
```

It might even clean up to this:

HAVING
      CASE @UserChoice 
        WHEN 1 THEN dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1 
        WHEN 2 THEN dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase2 
        ...
      END = 1

The problem (I believe; in sql server at least, not totally sure about SSRS) is that when you say:

```
CASE WHEN @UserChoice = 1 THEN 'dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1' END = '1'
```

Your case when is emitting the literal string `dbo.tblDocumentFact.useCase1` not the value of that column on that row. And of course this literal string is never equal to a literal string of `1`

Overall I prefer Tim's solution; I think the query optimizer will more likely be able to use an index on the bit columns in that form, but be aware that use of ORs can cause sql server to ignore indexes; the DBAs at my old place frequently rewrote queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName = 'john' OR LastName = 'Smith'
```

Into this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName = 'john' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE LastName = 'Smith'
```

Because the server wouldn't combine the index on FirstName and the other index on LastName when we used OR, but it would parallel execute using both indexes in the UNION form

Consider as an alternative, combining those bit flags into a single integer, either as a binary 2's complement (if you want to be able to say user choice 1 and 2 by searching for `3` or choice 2 and 4 and 6 by searching 42 [2^(2 -1) + 2^(4-1) + 2^(6-1)]) or just a straight int you can compare to @userChoice, and indexing it

Comment: Caius: Thanks very much for this expanded explanation.  I need to improve my understanding of SQL Server's utilization of indexes, query execution plans, query optimization, etc.